# Calculate $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^x}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I encountered this integral and I want to find its symbolic solution.

Since $x^2$ is in the denominator, we have $0< a< b$ to make sure the integrand value does not explode.

I did some search on Internet: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/integration-of-e-x-x-2-with-respect-to-x.225955/ and I saw someone says such integral does not have an elementary function form.

My question is: (1) does the solution exists? (2) If it exists, what is it? And why we cannot express it in some "nice" way?

Comment: Under your conditions, the function $e^x/x^2$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  Therefore the integral exists.  (This theorem should be in your calculus textbook.  It is due to Euler.)  Note that "almost no" integrable functions have  integrals that are expressed in some nice way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that can be expressed using real numbers, $x, e^x, \sin x, \cos x$ along with their inverses, and addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and function composition are often called "closed-form" functions.

Any closed-form function can be differentiated, and the result will be another closed-form function. However, the opposite is not true. Not every closed-form function is the derivative of another closed-form function. In fact, if you were to generate a bunch of closed-form functions at random, it is likely that most of the functions you generate will not be the derivative of another closed-form function. A couple of well-studied examples are the functions $$\frac{e^x}x\text{ and }\frac{\sin x}x$$
This is just a fact of mathematics, much like how you cannot express the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter as the ratio of two integers. Disturbing at first, but eventually you move on and stop worrying about it (certainly not something you'd invent a [holiday for to celebrate](https://www.piday.org/)). Sure, you will never know *exactly* what the value is, no matter how many trillions of digits are calculated. But knowing only the first five digits are sufficient for almost every practical calculation you will ever encounter.

$\int \frac{e^x}x\,dx$ is not a closed-form function. But it is a function (up to that ubiquitous additive constant). The definite integral $\int_a^b\frac{e^x}x\,dx$ for $a,b > 0$ is defined by a limiting process involving summations, not by means of anti-derivatives. For each $a,b > 0$, as long as that limiting process actually converges, there is a distinct real number that $\int_a^b\frac{e^x}x\,dx$ is defined to be. And because $\frac{e^x }x$ is continuous for $x > 0$, we can show that the limiting process does indeed converge. We cannot ever know *exactly* what that number is, but we can calculate however many digits of it we need by using that limiting process.

This is not some horrible thing. Even the $e^x$ inside the integral is the same way. The only value of $e^x$ which we know exactly is $e^0 = 1$. For every other $x$, either $x$ itself or $e^x$ is a number whose exact value we can never know. So while we don't have a nice closed-form function $f(x)$ for which we can say $\int_a^b\frac{e^x}x\,dx = f(b) - f(a)$, we can still be sure it exists. Instead we can use the integrability to define a new function

$$\text{Ei}(x) = -\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt$$

And be sure that this function exists, again because $\frac{e^{-t}}t$ is continuous (and because it decays fast enough to be finite even though the upper limit is at $\infty$). Then we can say that $$\int_a^b \frac{e^x}x\,dx = \text{Ei}(b) - \text{Ei}(a)$$ using certain properties of integrals.

What about your integral? Using integration-by-parts,
$$\int \frac{e^x}{x^2}\,dx = \int\frac1{x^2}\,de^x = \frac{e^x}{x^2} - \int e^x\,d\frac1{x^2} = \frac{e^x}{x^2} + \int \frac{e^x}x\,dx$$
So
$$\int_a^b \frac{e^x}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{e^b}{b^2} - \frac{e^a}{a^2} + \text{Ei}(b) - \text{Ei}(a)$$

Comment: What is the domain of $Ei(\cdot)$?

Comment: As i've defined it here, $(0,\infty)$. But using the Cauchy Principle Value at $0$, it can be extended to all of $\Bbb R$. You can research it under the name "Exponential integral".

Comment: Correction, the domain can be extended to $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$. Using the C.P.V. allows you to step over $0$, but the integral at $0$ is still infinite.